# use dataset variable to reference arrays

Tags: sas

is it possible to use a dataset colum (character variables) 
in a datastep to reference an arrays of the same name as the "character names"
in the column in a datastep.

An example:

```
data somedataset; 
  input id $ number; 
  DATALINES; 
dk33 50
dk34 100
;
run;

data test;
set somedataset;
ARRAY dk33{3} x1-x3 (10,2,3) ;
ARRAY dk34{3} y1-y3 (4,2,6)
res = id[1] + id[2] + id[3] + number  #what i want to do#
run;
```

As you see I want to use the "id" column to reference the array which I declared in the datastep. clearly id is character so it cant reference the array. However is there any solution to this? please help out...

Comment: It's not clear what ID[1] actually refers to here. You need to provide a better example of what you have and what you want as the output.

Answer (score 1):

No.  You could convert your character variable into an index into a two dimensional array.

If your names will have contiguous numeric suffixes like in your example just convert the suffix to a number to use as the index.

```
i=input(substr(in,3),32.)-32;
```

Here is a way using a list of names to lookup which index to use.

```
data test;
  set somedataset;
  array names (2) $32 _temporary_ ('dk33' 'dk34') ;
  array lookup (2,3) _temporary_ (10 2 3 , 4 2 6) ;
  i=whichc(id, of names(*) );
  res = lookup(i,1) + lookup(i,2) + lookup(i,3) + number ;
run;
```

Result:

```
Obs     id     number    i    res

 1     dk33       50     1     65
 2     dk34      100     2    112
```